# Como contar trabajadores mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query donde yo obtengo un listado de trabajos realizados por trabajos. Una operación puede tener muchos trabajos y así el trabajo puede ser realizados por muchos trabajos.

Aqui my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60ddbd/1). La info en el fiddle es:

```
CREATE TABLE  Operaciones (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `op` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `Operaciones`
--
INSERT INTO Operaciones
    (op)
VALUES
    ('Operacion1'),
    ('Operacion2');

CREATE TABLE  Trabajos (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_operaciones` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_work` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO Trabajos
    (id_operaciones,time_work, details)
VALUES
    (1,4,'Trabajo a Operacion1'),
    (1,2,'Trabajo a Operacion1 solo un trabajador'),
    (2,3,'Trabajo a Operacion2');

CREATE TABLE  Trabajodores (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_trabajos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_worker` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO Trabajodores
    (id_trabajos,id_worker)
VALUES
    (1,333),
    (1,444),
    (2,333),
    (3,444);
```

Lo que deseo es poder contar la cantidad de trabajadores que realizo en un trabajo. Como en el ejemplo el la operacion1 tiene 2 trabajos, pero uno de ellos lo fue realizado por 2 trabajos.

He intentado `COUNT( id_trabajos )`  o `COUNT (DISTINT id_trabajos)`, y obtengo 1.

La consulta de prueba en el fiddle es:

```
SELECT * FROM Operaciones as o 
LEFT JOIN Trabajos as t ON t.id_operaciones = o.id
LEFT JOIN Trabajodores AS b ON b.id_trabajos = t.id ORDER BY op ASC
```

Deseo algo asi

```
------------------------------------------
|op         |details|time| id_worker|count|
------------|-------|----|----------|-----
|Operacion1 |  op1  | 4  | 333      | 2   |
|Operacion1 |  op1  | 4  | 444      | 2   |
|Operacion1 |op1solo| 2  | 333      | 1   |
|Operacion2 |   op2 | 3  | 444      | 1   |
|-----------|-------|----|----------|-----|
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Perdón x el titulo cualquier sugerencia la acepto.

Comment: Serviría mucho a la pregunta, si agregas una muestra de los datos de salida que esperas obtener

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por tu recomendación

Comment: No termino de entender que necesitas.. dice trabajos muchas veces y no se a que campos te referis. Podrias tratar de aclarar un poco mejor los datos de entrada, y los datos de salida? esa ultima tabla no se que es ni se de donde sale cada campo

Comment: @gbianchi una operacion puede tener muchos trabajos, este trabajo realizado a una operacion puede tener muchos trabajos. Quiero poder contar cantidad de trabajadores que realizaron ese trabajo.

Comment: Necesitamos un ejemplo claro.. yo esos trabajos que vos decis no se de donde salen... pone un ejemplo clarito de las tablas y como vas contando (o querrias que cuente)

Comment: tu id_worker no tiene mucho sentido por favor si necesitas ayuda agrega un poco de datos reales(osea que tengan sentido pueden ser fake).

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo prueba con esto creo que es lo que necesitas
Por lo que entiendo el trabajo 1 se realizo dos veces y los otros dos solo una vez entonces para el primero debe de darte 2 en el count y 1 en los otros dos.

```
 SELECT O.op, details,id_operaciones,SUM(t.time_work) TimeFinal,GROUP_CONCAT(b.id_Worker) AS IDS_WORKERS, COUNT(*) AS CuantosTrabajadores
FROM Operaciones as o 
LEFT JOIN Trabajos as t ON t.id_operaciones = o.id
LEFT JOIN Trabajodores AS b ON b.id_trabajos = t.id 
GROUP BY details,id_operaciones,o.op
ORDER BY op ASC
```

Saludos
Prueba donde realize el test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60ddbd/58

Comment: Esta quedando afuera el dato `Trabajo a Operacion1 solo un trabajador`

Comment: Pero el resultado por ahi va para saber ?

Comment: Si algo asi quiero

Comment: Tengo lo que necesitas amigo tuve que hacer unos ajustes del por que no te funcionaba primero por lo de las horas no se sumanaban y los id de los trabajadores considero que como quedo te funcionara, si quisieras las horas separadas como los id de los trabajadores puedes hacer uso de la misma funcion en vez de la suma para ver las horas trabajadas de cada trabajador saludos